# My .yaml is not redirecting properly

Tags: python, google-app-engine, yaml

app.yaml

```
application: classscheduler9000
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:   
- url: /static
  static_dir: static

- url: /images
  static_dir: static/images

- url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: static/stylesheets

- url: /users\.html
  script: main.py

- url: /.*
  script: login.py
```

main.py

```
import hashlib

from google.appengine.api import users
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
from google.appengine.ext import db

class AccountHolder(db.Model):
    ...

class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
            ...

class UserWrite(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        ...

application = webapp.WSGIApplication(
                                     [('/', MainPage),
                                      ('/sign', UserWrite)],
                                     debug=True)

def getMD5Hash(textToHash=None):
    return hashlib.md5(textToHash).hexdigest()

def main():
    run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I'm currently testing this offline with Google App Engine. When I go to localhost:8080, It takes me to my login page. However, when I try to access localhost:8080/users.html, it doesn't load my main.py file (It errors out like a broken link). If I swap the urls, main.py works, but login.py won't load.

I know this is probably some stupid oversight on my part, and I couldn't find any help on google or this site. Thanks for any help.

Comment: What error shows up in the error log?  Post your main.py application definition.

Comment: There is no error log. It's has to be a semantic error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with your application definition.

```
application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/user\.html', MainPage),
                                      ('/sign', UserWrite)],
                                     debug=True)
```

The documentation about this is here, although it does not have "simple" examples.
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/running.html

Just a note, you do not need to use the .html.  Instead you can map '/user' in both places.